# How to replace the underscore with Hyphen using Htaccess rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, replace, url-rewriting

How to replace the underscore with Hyphen using Htaccess rule

Here is link:

http://iloansdirect.netsmartz.us/property_finder.shtml

I want to below link:

http://iloansdirect.netsmartz.us/property-finder.shtml

Comment: Can you show your current .htaccess rules?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I have tested it and it works for me.Restart Apache server and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can check below

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule !\.(html|php)$ - [S=6]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3-$4-$5-$6-$7 [E=underscores:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3-$4-$5-$6 [E=underscores:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3-$4-$5 [E=underscores:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3-$4 [E=underscores:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3 [E=underscores:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2 [E=underscores:Yes]

RewriteCond %{ENV:underscores} ^Yes$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.askapache.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

found at http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/rewrite-underscores-hyphens-seo-url.html