# Rewrite url not working with hyphen "-" using .htaccess with php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I'm trying to make my url user-friendly by using .htaccess rewrite.

from url - http://localhost/Web/new_products.php?cat_id=1&cat_title=new-rocket

to url - http://localhost/Web/new-rocket-1.php

**in my new_products.php**

```
$get_cat = "select * from new_products_cat";
$run_cat = mysqli_query($con, $get_cat);
while($row_cat = mysqli_fetch_array($run_cat)){
                    
$cat_id = $row_cat['cat_id'];
$cat_title = $row_cat['cat_title'];
$hyphen_cat_title = str_replace(' ', '-', $cat_title);
                    
echo "
<a href='new_products.php?cat_id=$cat_id&cat_title=$hyphen_cat_title'>
......
......
......
```

**in my .htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /Web/new_products.php\?cat_id=([^&\s]+)&cat_title=([^&\s]+) [NC]  
    RewriteRule ^ /Web/%2-%1\.php? [NC,R,L,NE]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^.]+)\.php$ /Web/new_products.php?cat_id=$2&cat_title=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

**Question 1**

My code working only if i use "underscore". **$hyphen_cat_title = str_replace(' ', '_', $cat_title);**

But not working if i use "hyphen", its keep redirecting to http://localhost/Web/new_products.php

**Question 2**

Can i replace "space" to "hyphen" using rewrite in .htaccess? without using php **str_replace**

Comment: 1: Your RewriteRule pattern uses the character group `[^-]` for matching the first part - “every character _but_ a hyphen.”

Comment: 2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754880/how-to-replace-the-underscore-with-hyphen-using-htaccess-rule

Comment: @CBroe Thanks in advance. Now its working after i change the last statement to `RewriteRule ^([^.]+)-([^.]+)\.php$ /Web/new_products.php?cat_id=$2&cat_title=$1 [QSA,L,NC]`. I'm not really understand the RewriteRule Expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my **Question 1**

The problem was [^-] “every character but a hyphen”. Thanks to [@CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe)

Below code fixed my problem.

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)-([^.]+)\.php$ /Web/new_products.php?cat_id=$2&cat_title=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```